# Why I can use a function to set a table index using arguments but i can't set a varble passed as a parameter

Tags: lua

im new to lua (and programming )
I would like to know why I can use a function to set a table index using arguments but i can't set a varble passed as a parameter like this :

```
variable = 1
function f(v)
  v = 2
end
f(variable)
print(variable)
--prints 1

function f(t,i)
  t[i] = 2
end
f(table,index)
print(table[1])
--prints 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Lua manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.5.1):

> Tables, functions, threads, and (full) userdata values are objects:
> variables do not actually contain these values, only references to
> them. Assignment, parameter passing, and function returns always
> manipulate references to such values; these operations do not imply
> any kind of copy

In your example variable is a number value which is none one of the mentioned types. Hence it is copied by value, not by reference.

So in

```
variable = 1
function f(v)
  v = 2
end
f(variable)
```

`v` is a copy of `variable`, local to `f`. Changing `v` does not affect `variable`.

In

```
function f(t,i)
  t[i] = 2
end
f(table,index)
print(table[1])
```

on the other hand, `t` is a reference to the same table, `table` refers to. Hence modifying `t` modifies the referred table.